# Paginator::url giving different results than Paginator::link

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP 1.3, according to the [docs](http://api.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelperurl) the `url()` method:

> returns a full pagination URL string for use in non-standard contexts (i.e. JavaScript)

This is what I need it for, JS. However if my current page's URL is:

> /admin/orders/index/page:1/to:2011-08-16

and I put this on my page:

```
echo $this->Paginator->url(array('from'=>'FROM_PLACE_HOLDER'));
echo $this->Paginator->link('test',array('from'=>'FROM_PLACE_HOLDER'));
```

The results are:

```
/admin/orders/index/page:1/from:FROM_PLACE_HOLDER
<a href="/admin/orders/index/page:1/to:2011-08-16/from:FROM_PLACE_HOLDER">test</a>
```

If you noticed, the `link()` method maintains the ***to*** param while the `url()` method resets it.

The strange part is I looked at the source for the `link()` method and it calls the `url()` method to get its URL. So something doesn't seem right.

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cake core code, it doesn't return directly from url(). I don't know the core code well enough, but I'd guess Paginator->link maintains all the non-paginator named parameters, while Paginator->url doesn't.

If you want url() to do the same, use

> ```
> $this->Paginator->url(array_merge($this->params['named'], array('from'=>'FROM_PLACE_HOLDER')));
> ```

or $this->passedArgs to preserve all args.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails I can use the link() method and extract the URL from it like this:

```
$url = preg_replace(
    '/.*href="([^"]+)".*/', 
    "$1", 
    $this->Paginator->link('test',array('from'=>'FROM_PLACE_HOLDER'))
);
```

Seems pretty dirty to have to result to something like this though.